# Google Admin SDK Directory API User Privileges

Tags: google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-api-php-client

Can a normal user account in my domain access the function on Google OAuth2 directory service API to retrieve users list or data ?

I have a web-application which allow the users to login with OAuth2.0. After that, the users should be able to see their profile data.

If I am using a super admin login, everything work just fine which the data is displayed. When I am using a normal user login and a group admin login, I cannot see any data and receive error message as follow:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/yifei.liu@example.com?key=(MY_API_Key): (403) Not Authorized to access this resource/api' in /home2/iaapro/public_html/php/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php:66 Stack trace: #0 /home2/iaapro/public_html/php/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php(36): Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) 
#1 /home2/iaapro/public_html/php/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(186): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) 
#2 /home2/iaapro/public_html/php/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DirectoryService.php(653): Google_ServiceResource->__call('get', Array) 
#3 /home2/iaapro/public_html/php/google-plus-access.php(47): Google_UsersServiceResource->get('yifei.liu@iaapr...') 
#4 /home2/iaapro/public_html/php/index.php(2): include_once('/home2/iaapro/p...') 
#5 {main} thrown in /home2/iaapro/public_html/php/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php on line 66
```

Does it mean that only account with domain super admin rights can access the Google Admin SDK Directory API ? Is it possible for me to allow normal user to use this API too ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share with the people a piece of your code and see where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A normal user **can** retrieve **Directory** contacts for your domain in read-only mode.  They can't make **changes** to anything in the **Directory**.

To list Directory contacts, you'll need to

```
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly");
```

in your oauth flow.

Then to retrieve, do something like this:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$optParams = array(
        'domain' => 'google.domain.com',
        'orderBy' => 'email',
        'viewType' => 'domain_public',
        'query' => "givenName:'Joe' familyName:'Schmoe Jr'"
);
$results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
$users = $results->getUsers();
```

You can also do this entirely via a service account, in which case your user never needs to go through the oauth step.  See here for a working example: [Google php client library loadServiceAccountJson broken - fix enclosed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615781/google-php-client-library-loadserviceaccountjson-broken-fix-enclosed)

Answer (score 0):

No. A "normal" user can not manage the **users** of your domain. For example, only **Admin accounts** can Create, Delete or update info. about the users.

Please, take a look in the [Admin SDK page](http://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory) If you want to manage contacts

A "normal" user can manage his/her **contacts**. They can see the email, telephone number, labels, etc., etc.

You can visit  visit [Google contacts API V3](http://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3) for more information about it.